# if huge array is faster than hash-map for look-up?

Tags: algorithm

I'm receiving "order update" from stock exchange. Each order id is between 1 and 100 000 000, so I can use 100 million array to store 100 million orders and when update is received I can look-up order from array very fast just accessing it by index `arrray[orderId]`. I will spent several gigabytes of memory but this is OK.

Alternatively I can use hashmap, and because at any moment the number of "active" orders is limited (to, very roughly, 100 000), look-up will be pretty fast too, but probaly a little bit slower then array.

The question is - will hashmap be actually slower? Is it reasonably to create 100 millions array?

I need **latency** and nothing else, I completely don't care about memory, what should I choose?

Comment: Profile.  Don't speculate.  Run it under the profiler with a real workload and find out which is faster.

Comment: I think you may (possibly) have to care about the memory-sonsumption, because if the operating system starts to swap your array to disk, you may comeinter severe trouble.

Comment: 100 million 64-bit integers is less than 800MB.  It's relatively easy to convince most modern operating systems to not page a working set of this size through judicious use of `madvise` and `mlock`.

Comment: Please don't feed the quants. They'll bite.

Comment: Isn't there some limit on the order ids? Something like, “today, the ids will be between 68 000 000 and 70 000 000”?

Comment: what's the miss ratio? how often do you look up things which don't exist in your map? are the active (100,000) orders the total you store, or the total that will be potentially queried?

Comment: @Christian You can prevent memory from being swapped to disk via this function **int mlock(const void *addr, size_t len);** (Linux)  locks pages in the address range starting at addr and continuing for len bytes. All pages that contain a part of the specified address range are guaranteed to be resident in RAM when the call returns successfully; the pages are guaranteed to stay in RAM until later unlocked.

Comment: Actually, this question seems strange to me. The OP says **I'm receiving "order update" from stock exchange.** which must be an update for an existing order with the **same id** and he therefore must have already used a technique to store the information for this order. Why not just use the same technique?

Comment: @Marichyasana The approximate equivalent for Windows is `VirtualLock` (for the sake of completeness, since the OP never specified which OS he is using).

Comment: Suppose that you found a magic way to do these lookups so that they cost zero cycles. The program executes a special instruction and the result comes back in the same clock cycle. What would be the speedup of the overall software? That speedup is the upper bound of what you can hope to get out of any possible optimization of the lookup.

Comment: 100,000 - is total stored items. i never look-up things that don't exist, i either add order (and then i know it doesn't exist) or delete/modify (and then i know it exist). I think i will store structures in array/hashmap, each structure is several dozens byte, but i can store pointer too if it's better... Overall speed-up will be several to dozens microseconds and this is good speed-up.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Whenever considering performance issues, one experiment is worth a thousand expert opinions.  Test it!

That said, I'll take a wild stab in the dark:  it's likely that if you can convince your OS to keep your multi-gigabyte array resident in physical memory (this isn't necessarily easy - consider looking at the `mlock` and `munlock` syscalls), you'll have relatively better performance.  Any such performance gain you notice (should one exist) will likely be by virtue of bypassing the cost of the hashing function, and avoiding the overheads associated with whichever collision-resolution and memory allocation strategies your hashmap implementation uses.

It's also worth cautioning that many hash table implementations have non-constant complexity for some operations (e.g., separate chaining could degrade to `O(n)` in the worst case).  Given that you are attempting to optimize for latency, an array with very aggressive signaling to the OS memory manager (e.g., `madvise` and `mlock`) are likely to result in the closest to constant-latency lookups that you can get on a microprocessor easily.

Comment: On the other hand, 100,000 records of the hashtable could potentially fit into the last-level CPU cache (assuming relatively small records), which is definitely not true for 100,000,000 records of the array (even if we just store pointers in the array). Will that be enough to offset the hashtable overhead? Who knows... you are very right that "one experiment is worth a thousand expert opinions" (+1 for that).

Comment: You're right, although many hash table implementations are likely to just store references to things elsewhere in memory, giving (potentially) very poor memory locality characteristics.

Comment: unless the orders are tiny objects, you want to store references in the array too...

Comment: i will store structures, not references or pointer in both array and hashmap

Comment: @javapowered Then using the array potentially becomes even worse! A "mere" 8 bytes (or, say, a 64-bit integer) means that it is 800MB of usage. Now, say if 40 bytes of information is needed (I don't actually know what is required), then it balloons to 4GB! There is just so much "unused" space.

Comment: @user2246674 i have 128 gigabytes of free memory so it's ok to use it

Comment: @javapowered It's not just having free memory - although that is *a lot*! There be other gremlins than can slip in due to cache sizes and misses. Since this sounds like a big project, I would implement at least two different "backends" for this (the simple array, then some form of a compressed map such as a hashtable); at the very least it will allow personal investigation between the different techniques and lead to some good performance testing (which I find fun). Also, just because resources are available doesn't mean they *need* to be used; unless doing so results in an advantage.

Answer (score 8):

While the *only way* to objectively answer this question is with performance tests, I will argue for using a Hashtable Map. (Caching and memory access can be so full of surprises; I do not have the expertise to speculate on which one will be faster, and when. Also consider that localized performance differences may be marginalized by other code.)

My first reason for "initially choosing" a hash is based off of the observation that there are 100M distinct keys but *only* 0.1M active records. This means that **if using an array, index utilization will only be 0.1%** - this is a *very sparse* array.

If the data is stored *as values in* the array then it needs to be relatively small or the array size will balloon. If the data is *not* stored in the array (e.g. array is of pointers) then the argument for locality of data in the array is partially mitigated. Either way, the simple array approach requires *lots of unused space*.

Since all the keys are already integers, **the distribution (hash) function and can be efficiently implemented** - there is no need to create a hash of a complex type/sequence so the "cost" of this function should approach zero.

So, my simple proposed hash:

- Use *linear probing* backed by contiguous memory. It is simple, has good locality (especially during the probe), and avoids needing to do any form of dynamic allocation.
- Pick a suitable initial bucket size; say, 2x (or 0.2M buckets, primed). Don't even give the hash a chance of resize. Note that this suggested bucket array size is only *0.2%* the size of the simple array approach and could be reduced further as the size vs. collision rate can be tuned.
- Create a good distribution function for the hash. It can also exploit knowledge of the ID range.

While I've presented specialized hashtable rules "optimized" for the given case, I would start with a normal Map implementation (be it a hashtable or tree) and test it .. if a standard implementation works suitably well, why not use it?

Now, test different candidates under expected and extreme loads - and pick the winner.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to depend on the clustering of the IDs.

If the active IDs are clustered suitably already then, without hashing, the OS and/or L2 cache have a fair shot at holding on to the good data and keeping it low-latency.

If they're completely random then you're going to suffer just as soon as the number of active transactions exceeds the number of available cache lines or the size of those transactions exceeds the size of the cache (it's not clear which is likely to happen first in your case).

However, if the active IDs work out to have some unfortunate pattern which causes a high rate of contention (eg., it's a bit-pack of different attributes, and the frequently-varying attribute hits the hardware where it hurts), then you might benefit from using a 1:1 hash of the index to get back to the random case, even though that's usually considered a pretty bad case on its own.

As far as hashing for compaction goes; noting that some people are concerned about worst-case fallback behaviour for a hash collision, you might simply implement a cache of the full-sized table in contiguous memory, since that has a reasonably constrained worst case.  Simply keep the busiest entry in the map, and fall back to the full table on collisions.  Move the other entry into the map if it's more active (if you can find a suitable algorithm to decide this).

Even so, it's not clear that the necessary hash table size is sufficient to reduce the working set to being cacheable.  How big are your orders?

Answer (score 0):

The overhead of a hashmap vs. an array is almost none. I would bet on a hashmap of 100,000 records over an array of 100,000,000, without a doubt.

Remember also that, while you "don't care about memory", this also means you'd better have the memory to back it up - an array of 100,000,000 integers will take up 400mb, even if all of them are empty. You run the risk of your data being swapped out. If your data gets swapped out, you will get a performance hit of several orders of magnitude.

Comment: "The overhead of a hashmap vs. an array is almost none" sounds like a bold claim.  I would usually think of a hashmap as being a way of trading off (greater) time for (less) space.  Particularly for 100,000,000 integers, the collision rate is going to be relatively high, at which point the collision mitigation strategy cost is going to become relatively likely to be applied to every insertion. Appropriately tuning the load factor of a 100,000,000 element hash table is a completely non-trivial task.

Comment: The overhead of hashing is basically 2* sizeof (index) per item, using separate chaining, given N=M.

Comment: And worst-case `O(n)` lookups.  The question *did* specify that it was an attempt to optimize for latency, which means that any potentially non-constant access time would be a trade-off in the wrong direction.

Comment: It would be a major effort to approach worst case with 100M items, IMHO.

Comment: @Gian: "Particularly for 100,000,000 integers, the collision rate is going to be relatively high" - this sentence doesn't make any sense. the collision rate is not dependent on the range of the possible keys. it only depends on the load factor. "Appropriately tuning the load factor of a 100,000,000 element hash table is a completely non-trivial task." 1) the table will have only 100,000 used elements.. 2) I don't see why the tuning would be more difficult for a bigger table. the maths behind it are completely the same.

Comment: The question specifies that there are 100 million orders, 100k of which are active at any given time.  One still needs to store the others, as I understand it.  The probability of a collision occurring tends to 1 as the number of keys tends to infinity, which was the only reason I suggested that collisions became more likely.

Comment: My understanding is that most implementations increase the number of buckets as the number of keys increase. Collisions are "likely" even when the number of keys is small - [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) says that 2,500 keys and one million buckets results in a 95% chance that there is a collision. Additionally, an array will [neccesarily] either be limited to a SINGLE CONSECUTIVE memory block (which I think also means the block is swapped in/out as a unit), OR will have a level of indirection, adding overhead.

Comment: A quick and dirty test shows that perl on my machine balks at an array of 300 million records (only one which has any actual data). method: `perl -e '$a[300000000]=1` - Out of memory!

Answer (score 0):

You should test and profile, as others have said.  My random stab in the dark, though:  A high-load-factor hash table will be the way to go here.  One huge array is going to cost you a TLB miss and then a last-level cache miss per access.  This is expensive.  A hash table, given the working set size you mentioned, is probably only going to cost some arithmetic and an L1 miss.

Again, test both alternatives on representative examples.  We're all just stabbing in the dark.